error: call to undeclared function 'OPENSSL_sk_find_all'
Trying to install M2Crypto==0.41.0 on Python 3.10 on OSX v13, but got a lot of similar errors like:
src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10746:17: error: call to undeclared function 'OPENSSL_sk_find_all'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        result = (int)OPENSSL_sk_find_all(arg1,(void const *)arg2,arg3);
                      ^
      src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10746:17: note: did you mean 'OPENSSL_sk_find_ex'?
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/include/openssl/stack.h:41:5: note: 'OPENSSL_sk_find_ex' declared here
      int OPENSSL_sk_find_ex(OPENSSL_STACK *st, const void *data);
          ^
      src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10991:20: error: call to undeclared function 'ossl_check_OPENSSL_STRING_type'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        result = (char *)ossl_check_OPENSSL_STRING_type(arg1);
                         ^
      src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10991:20: note: did you mean '_wrap_ossl_check_OPENSSL_STRING_type'?
      src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10975:22: note: '_wrap_ossl_check_OPENSSL_STRING_type' declared here
      SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_ossl_check_OPENSSL_STRING_type(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
                           ^
      src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10991:12: warning: cast to 'char *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        result = (char *)ossl_check_OPENSSL_STRING_type(arg1);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Already tried to brew reinstall swig and googled possible answers but to no avail.

Problem was I was using the wrong LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS which were pointing to openssl v1.
After updating to them to point to openssl v3 then the error went away.
export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/include"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/lib"

